# Retrieving a div using id and .get?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to retrieve a div using ajax .get and its ID attribute.  The ajax call works but it returns the full page instead of just the div of id top.

```
$.get(page + ' #top', function(data){
    topContent= data;
});
```

Page is just the url of the page eg: gridpView.php. The above code works perfectly with the .load function.  I am trying to load in several div's before I use them so load is not an option.

What am I doing wrong? Is the .get function capable of retrieving a div?

Comment: You could use `.load()` on detached elements (elements that are not in the live DOM)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sort of thing works with `load` but I don't believe it works with `get`.  You'll need to get the whole page and then grab the part you want:

```
$.get(page, function(data){
    topContent=$(data).find("#top");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will gives you the content of he div

```
 topContent= $('#top').html();
```